# Intersection Observer invoking function for 1 time

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I just made an Intersection observer to invoke function whenever it fired up. but it just working for one time. it's invoking function just for one time not every time that it's intersecting.
Here's the code , I wanna Invoke function called type for typing effect when it's Intersecting "section"
but it's working for 1 time

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries,observer){
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        console.log(entry);
        if(entry.isIntersecting){
           type();
        }
    });
},options);
observer.observe(section);
```

Comment: see if it helps if you add something like `entry.boundingClientRect.y > 100` to your if statement or play around with the `rootMargin` in options

Comment: you need to send a threshold such as `[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9]` to have greedier notifications. It's unfortunately a static list of possibilities, but once you define those, it'll trigger more often.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi I tried threshold. it's working fine. I saw in console. but it just working for 1 time

Comment: @zergski Intersection observer working very well. it's turning false in proper time and also true in proper time. but it just invoking function for 1 time. even when you scroll the page and "IsIntersecting" changing to true. it's not working again

Comment: so, if you use `{threshold: .2}`, as example, it should notify while scrolling, at least that's my *production* experience, so check out why that's not the case for you, as specs say it should trigger, and it does in my projects.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi Thank you for giving time to my problem. I found it. you can see my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. every time that function invokes it changes variable so I need to reset them.
to doing this I can add an else block and reset all variables there.
If you have better idea share with me.
thanks